# How to connect remotely from Windows to Mac from LAN

Tags: windows, macos, controls

Basically what I want to do is write iOS code on Xcode from my Windows PC which is connected to my Macbookpro. I tried a lot of applications for this and most of them connect through the internet and have screen action delays. Some of the other applications have a problem with sending mac commands from my windows keyboard.

So:
 - Fast LAN connection
 - Ability to pass mac shortcuts
 - Responsive
 - Hopefully free
 - Hopefully copy paste data between computers

Answer (score 0):

to state the obvious,so we are on the same page.  the LAN is your Local Area Network, and the parameters of your LAN are defined by the Coverage area of your Modem's Wifi Range and the amount of Ethernet Hard Wire Connections,  if you are trying to connect to a Mac on your LAN From a Windows Machine on the same LAN,  That is not referred to as REMOTE CONNECTION,  That is referred to as LOCAL NETWORKING,  Connecting Remotely, or Remote Connection is when you connect From a Remote LAN or one that is not Your Personal LAN, and you use that LAN to Connect to a Computer on your LAN,  that's remote connection, Hence, your connecting remotely,  so.. Are you using Your LAN to achieve this and your having lag issues, or a you trying to do it remotely,  if your trying to Remote Connect and your having trouble with Software, because i know it can be a pain, You should have mentioned what you have already tried,  But.. Windows Remote Desktop Connection is buggy, i wouldn't recommend it, the way to go use to be TeamViewer as a free solution, then they Stopped the Free thing and started charging, Other Options were CrossLoop, it's good, but sometimes slow, Try if you haven't already, Most of the Good option are Paid, i rate Bomgar to be the highest, because your accessing Remotely via way of a Remote Box that is not technically inside the parameters of your LAN, hence more secure. LogMeIn is a good one
but as far as free is concerned, and to get the results you want, there is not much out there, obviously the idea is that they want you to buy the full versions, i'll do some research for you, but.. is it possible for you to provide a list of what you have already experimented with thus far, so i don't double handle.  thanks

Comment: It is LAN connection then. I do not want internet to be involved in this connection because it devours the bandwidth and is too laggy. I tried WinRDC and TeamV, realvnc. I checked logmein but seemed to expensive with yearly payment. 
Of course if there is another solution, like USB connecting my laptop & pc and somehow working this out with a different type of software, that kind of solution will work for me as well.

Comment: If it's on your Local Area Network at your place and all your trying to do is connect Your PC to your Mac, and avoid using internet, that's easy, Use Windows Remote Desktop Connection, it's not the best thing when your actually Remotely connecting from outside your LAN, but, if you within your LAN, Use it, All Techies do to access the Server Room from their Workstation, it's common Place, to help with speed, ensure that are Using a Gigabit Ethernet Switch, if you want to exclude internet then get the Modem out of the equation and make sure all Ports are Gigabit Capable, that'll work well.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems with Windows RDC on Your LAN, Why have you chosen to not go with it thus far ?

Comment: It seems RDC cannot access the mac for some reason. I can access the pc from mac but not the otherway around

Comment: Hey mate, Ok,  well it seems to me that as long as you connect Mac to PC and PC to Mac, Any Remote software should do the job, since it's a LAN, Try some of these out and see how you go, PS, When LogMeIn went out of FREE support, i remembered one that i tried but can't manage to find it right now, i'll keep looking, it looked pretty good and if i remember it was cross platform compatible,  I'll keep looking for it, in the meantime try these out and see how you [http://pcsupport.about.com/od/remote-access/tp/free-remote-access-software.htm]